# Shortest paths problem with two conditions

Tags: algorithm, graph

Let's say i have a directed graph G(V,E,w,c) where w is the positive weight of each edge and c is the cost of every edge being either 1 or 0.I need to find an algorithm that for given source vertice u finds the shortest paths from u to every vertice in V that have cost ≤ k(where k≥1).

I tried modifying Bellman ford's algorithm but i can't seem to find the solution.

Comment: I don't think you can easily make Bellman-Ford work for this problem. I think modifying Dijkstra will be easier especially since you are interested in distances from just one source.

Comment: @SergGr I think this could not be solved with a greedy method because only after finding the minimum path to a vertice we know if it is within the boundaries of k.

Comment: Epitheoritis, if you look closely to @btilly answer you may notice that this is exactly modified Dijkstra and I don't see reason why it would not work (if implemented properly which I think that answer is not that clear about). Do you have any counter-examples?

Comment: The main idea is that when doing Dijkstra you can safely cut early the branches that break your `total_cost >= k` restriction. You still potentially need to check more paths candidates because having lower weight is not a guarantee of being better because we might not have enough cost left to reach the finish. But still it is not hard to implement.

Comment: @SergGr That's what i meant:consider having edges A->B with cost=10 weight=20,another A->B with cost 12 and weight=5,B->C cost=7 weight=1,another B->C cost=5 weight=50.We should not secure A->B(12,5) in the shortest path tree despite being the best for visiting only B.This could only be understood after visiting C though.

Comment: I still don't understand where you see the problem. Even with the pure Dijkstra algorithm we might update best path to a give node a few times before we mark it as visited. So where is the problem in considering a few paths from that node either explicitly or implicitly as done by @btilly by storing the path candidates in the queue instead of the graph?

Comment: @SergGr How would the algorithm work for my example then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me restate my understanding of the problem.

For all vertices that you can reach with a cost of no more than `k`, you want the path of minimal weight that gets there from a vertex `u`.

You need a combination of ideas to get there.

Suppose that a `RouteToNode` object has the following attributes:  `cost`, `weight`, `node`, `lastRouteToNode` and an autoincrementing `id`.  This is a linked list carrying us back to the original node, letting us reconstruct the route.  We compare them by `cost`, then `weight`, then `id`.

We have a hash/dictionary/whatever you want to call it that maps nodes to the lowest weight `RouteToNode` object reaching that node.  Call it `bestRoute`.

We have a `todo` list that has `RouteToNode`s that we have not yet processed which is a priority queue that always returns the minimal `RouteToNode`.  Note that it always returns them from lowest cost to highest.

We start with `bestRoute` having nothing in it, and a `todo` queue with only a single `RouteToNode`, namely:

```
{
    id: 0,
    cost: 0,
    weight: 0,
    node: u,
    lastRouteToNode: null
}
```

And now we execute the following pseudocode:

```
while todo is not empty:
    thisRouteToNode = todo.pop()
    if thisRouteToNode.node not in bestRoute or
      thisRouteToNode.weight < bestRoute[thisRouteToNode.node].weight:
        bestRoute[thisRouteToNode.node] = thisRouteToNode
        for edge adjacent to thisRouteToNode.node:
            construct nextRouteToNode by adding edge
            if nextRouteToNode.cost <= k:
                todo.push(nextRouteToNode)
```

Comment: What is the time complecity here?

Comment: @Epitheoritis32 The worst case is `O(k E log(k E))`.  That represents the situation where you visit nodes over and over again at ever reduced costs, and put all of their edges into the todo list.  That said, in practice I would expect you to be closer to `O(E log(E))`.